# only use jQuery slideshow if div has more than 1 image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to only use a jQuery slideshow only if that div has more than one image, any idea what's wrong here?

```
if(.portfolio-featured img.length > 1) {
   jQuery('.portfolio-featured').fadeSlideShow({
        width: 937,
        height: 600,
        interval: 6000
  });
} 
else {
  // do nothing here.
}
```

Comment: `.portfolio-featured img.length` is not a valid JavaScript expression.

Comment: Open console F12 and see what is wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

`.portfolio-featured img.length` is invalid JavaScript. You need to pass everything but `.length` to jQuery as a string, then get the length of the elements returned by that selector.

```
if(jQuery('.portfolio-featured img').length > 1) {
   jQuery('.portfolio-featured').fadeSlideShow({
        width: 937,
        height: 600,
        interval: 6000
  });
} 
else {
  // do nothing here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
   if( $(".portfolio-featured img").length > 1 ){
     //check..
  }
```